# Searching for a specific file name across websites on Wayback Machine

Tags: web-crawling, html, archive.org

Is there any way to find all occurrences of some file on the entire internet, as captured by the Internet Archive? I want to wildcard-search for a filename.

Of course, this doesn't make sense with basic filenames like `index.php`, but say you are looking for `OOo_1.0.3.1_Win32Intel_install.zip` but cannot find it anywhere using regular live search engines – can the Wayback Machine help with that? https://web.archive.org/web/*/*OOo_1.0.3.1_Win32Intel_install.zip e.g. would not not return anything. But it looks like it should: There **is** https://web.archive.org/web/20150411035821/http://download.oldapps.com/OpenOffice/OOo_1.0.3.1_Win32Intel_install.zip.

And if not directly, maybe using the [Python library](https://archive.org/services/docs/api/internetarchive/index.html)? The documentation did not help out, neither did the [Search Guide](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360018359991-Search-A-Basic-Guide) or the [WM FAQ](https://help.archive.org/hc/en-us/articles/360004651732-Using-The-Wayback-Machine). Maybe there is a mirror for some kind of WA metadata database that you can download, so you can build your own queries? Did not find anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now contacted the IA directly and Mark Graham kindly told me that this is impossible, as there is no fts url index.